# How do I correct "This webpage has a redirect loop" error when redirecting to HTTPS?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a domain/DNS registered with A and the site itself on B, a cloud sites provider.  On B I have the SSL cert installed.  Both the http and https URL work when used.  I want to redirect all http traffic to https.  So I made a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainhere.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It redirects to the https site in the URL but doesn't load the site.  The error says "This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS."  Is this because the route is going to A which is told to go to B?  If so what is the solution?  If not, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh figured it out!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainhere.com/$1 [R,L]
```